# Unchanged objects in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I have silverlight application.
This is an invoke operation (in Open Ria Service - WCF Ria Service open source version) with Entity Framework 6.

```
    public List<VaultAmount> GetCurrentVaultAmounts(Guid vaultId)
    {
        return this.DbContext.VaultAmounts
            .Include(v => v.VaultAmountQuantities)
            .Include(v => v.VaultCurrency)
            .Include(v => v.Vault)
            .Include(v => v.VaultAmountQuantities.Select(vaq => vaq.VaultCurrency))
            .Where(v => v.VaultId == vaultId && v.IsCurrent).ToList();
    }

    [Invoke]
    public void UpdateVaultRemainders(List<VaultAmountQuantity> updatedQuantities, string comment, Guid userId,
        string friendlyName,
        Guid vaultAmountId, int currencyId)
    {
        VaultAmount vaultAmount =
            this.DbContext.VaultAmounts
                .Include("Vault")
                .SingleOrDefault(va => va.VaultAmountId == vaultAmountId);

        if (vaultAmount == null && vaultAmount.Vault == null) return;

        //Get FromVault and ToVault with amounts and updatedQuantities
        List<VaultAmount> currentAmounts = GetCurrentVaultAmounts(vaultAmount.Vault.VaultId);
        //Vault vault = GetVaultWithCurrentAmountsAndQuantitiesById(vaultAmount.Vault.VaultId);

        var helper = new RemainderVAHelper(currentAmounts, userId, friendlyName, currencyId, updatedQuantities,
            comment,
            BS2VaultEventTypes.Correction);

        //................................

        foreach (var amount in currentAmounts)
        {
            if (amount.IsCurrent == false)
            {
                DbEntityEntry<VaultAmount> entityEntry = this.DbContext.Entry(amount);
                entityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

In **RemainderVAHelper** class I am changing **currentAmounts** objects, set **IsCurrent** property to false.
But **currentAmounts** objects **entityEntry.State** are still **Unchanged**. Why? Yes, I can set their states as **Modified** (as I am doing in method), but I think it is not very good thing. Can you tell me why my objects state doesn't changes to **Modified**?

Comment: Are your objects in an "attached state" to the context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using change tracking proxies EF has no way of knowing you modified a property until you call DetectChanges or call SaveChanges (which calls DetectChanges)

Comment: Actually, yes. I have added a line: var detect = DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled; and detect was false. Thanks a lot. How to set this option to true, to all my domain services?

Comment: It's interesting because the default setting is `true` and from what I looked into the EF code EF does not set it to `false`